# Let $p:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial. Prove $\exists$ a polynomial $q$ with rational coefficients s.t. $\Vert p-q \Vert_\infty \lt \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, polynomials

> Let $p:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial. Prove that for every
>   $\epsilon \gt0, \exists$ a polynomial $q:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with
>   **rational** coefficients s.t. $\Vert p-q \Vert_\infty \lt \epsilon$.

My overall approach is in constructing a polynomial with rational coefficients.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given and let a polynomial $p$ be given. Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ a_2x^2 +\dots+ a_nx^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

Define a polynomial $q(x) = b_0 + b_1x +\dots+b_nx^n$, where each coefficient $b_i$ is defined by:

$\displaystyle b_i = \frac{l_i}{m_i}$ where $l_i,m_i \in \mathbb{N}, m_i \neq 0$, s.t. $\displaystyle \left| \frac{l_i}{m_i} -a_i \right| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{n+1}$.

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle
|p(x)-q(x)| & = \left| \left(a_0-\frac{l_0}{m_0}\right) + \left(a_1-\frac{l_1}{m_1}\right)x + \dots + \left(a_n-\frac{l_n}{m_n}\right)x^n\right| \\
& \leq \left| a_0-\frac{l_0}{m_0} \right| + \left| a_1-\frac{l_1}{m_1} \right| \cdot |x| + \dots + \left| a_n-\frac{l_n}{m_n} \right| \cdot |x^n| \\
& \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n+1} + \frac{\epsilon}{n+1} \cdot |x| + \dots + \frac{\epsilon}{n+1} \cdot |x^n| \\
& \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n+1} (n+1) \\
& = \epsilon .
\end{align}
$$

So $|p(x) - q(x)| \lt \epsilon, \ \forall x \in [-1,1]$, then $\Vert p-q \Vert_\infty \lt \epsilon$.

$\Box$

I would like some feedback on overall correctness, style as well as simplification if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Your proof is correct. It would be notationally simpler to not specify the $b_i$ as fractions, seeing as how that is irrelevant to the matter at hand; in the sense that they key property of $\mathbb{Q}$ is its density. Indeed, your proof works for polynomials with coefficients in any dense set.

Comment: As  @Reveillark said, just say $ b_i\in \Bbb Q$ and replace each  $l_i/m_i$ with $b_i$.... And for better style, before in the main display about $p(x)-q(x)$, replace "Then" with "Then for all $x\in [0,1]$ we have".  Quite correct work.

Comment: My edit was to put a period after $\epsilon$ in the 2nd-last line. I commend you for your style: Grammatically complete sentences, logically related.

Comment: You could also employ the summation notation $\sum$ instead of $+...+$ but I would call this a matter of taste. But in the section about $|p(x)-q(x)|$ you should erase the terms that include $a_1,$ because they are unneeded and because  it may be that $n=0.$... I have some mistakes in my other comments but it's too late to edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compact way of writing, maybe:

Choose $b_{i}\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|a_{i}-b_{i}|<\epsilon/(n+1)$, then for $x\in[-1,1]$,
\begin{align*}
|p(x)-q(x)|&=\left|\sum_{i=0}^{n}(a_{i}-b_{i})x^{i}\right|\\
&\leq\sum_{i=0}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}||x|^{i}\\
&\leq\sum_{i=0}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}|\\
&<\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{\epsilon}{n+1}\\
&=\epsilon,
\end{align*}
so $\|p-q\|\leq\epsilon$.